# jQuery Deferred multiple handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to the jQuery documentation (https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/), it should be possible to pass multiple success or failure callbacks to `.then()` as arrays of functions. However, it doesn't appear to function as specified.

It does seem to function as expected with .done() and .fail().

Is this a jQuery bug, or am I missing something?

```js
$(() => {
  $.Deferred().resolve('Fulfilled')
    .then([
        (m) => {
            console.log(m, 'Then Fulfilled 1')
            return $.Deferred().resolve(m)
          },
        (m) => {
            console.log(m, 'Then Fulfilled 2')
            return $.Deferred().resolve(m)
          }
      ], [
        (m) => {
            console.log(m, 'Then Rejected 1')
            return $.Deferred().reject(m)
          },
        (m) => {
            console.log(m, 'Then Rejected 2')
            return $.Deferred().reject(m)
          }
      ])
    .done([
        (m) => {
            console.log(m, 'Done 1')
            return $.Deferred().resolve(m)
          },
        (m) => {
            console.log(m, 'Done 2')
            return $.Deferred().resolve(m)
          }
      ])
    .fail([
        (m) => {
            console.log(m, 'Fail 1')
            return $.Deferred().reject(m)
          },
        (m) => {
            console.log(m, 'Fail 2')
            return $.Deferred().reject(m)
          }
    ])
  $.Deferred().reject('Rejected')
    .then([
        (m) => {
            console.log(m, 'Then Fulfilled 1')
            return $.Deferred().resolve(m)
          },
        (m) => {
            console.log(m, 'Then Fulfilled 2')
            return $.Deferred().resolve(m)
          }
      ], [
        (m) => {
            console.log(m, 'Then Rejected 1')
            return $.Deferred().reject(m)
          },
        (m) => {
            console.log(m, 'Then Rejected 2')
            return $.Deferred().reject(m)
          }
      ])
    .done([
        (m) => {
            console.log(m, 'Done 1')
            return $.Deferred().resolve(m)
          },
        (m) => {
            console.log(m, 'Done 2')
            return $.Deferred().resolve(m)
          }
      ])
    .fail([
        (m) => {
            console.log(m, 'Fail 1')
            return $.Deferred().reject(m)
          },
        (m) => {
            console.log(m, 'Fail 2')
            return $.Deferred().reject(m)
          }
    ])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is your use case for needing an array of functions to pass to `then()`? Should probably ignore jQuery `$.Deferred` and use more modern Promise API

Comment: @charlietfl I was dealing with some code using jQuery ajax, and needed to attach multiple handlers, and the array option seemed convenient. There was also a need to chain handlers with multiple arguments (not demonstrated in the given snippet). Also, I didn't wish to require additional includes if I could avoid it...